# Drawing a sqaure on an axis in Java

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to write a program that draws a sqaure.
The user will enter the size (in the length of the sides),  the x-coordinate, and the y-coordinate of the bottom-left corner of the square on the grid as command-line parameters to program, in that order.

So an input of "run   Question2Square  5   1   1"
draws a square of side length 5 whose bottom left corner is at the position (1, 1).

I've spent a few hours trying to just get the axes to show up correctly. I'm not even on the square yet.

My current code I have is this, but it's wrong:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question2square {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Axis variables
    int yAxismin = 0;
    int yAxismax = 15;
    int xAxismin = 0;
    int xAxismax = 15;

    //Loop through all coordinates on plane using for loops
    for(int y = yAxismin; y >= yAxismin; y++)
    {
      for(int x = xAxismin; x >= xAxismin; x++)
      {
        //Draw the axis 
        if (Axis(x,y) != "") {
          System.out.print(Axis (x,y));
        }
      }
      System.out.println("");
    }
  }
  // This method draws the 15x15 axis
  public static String Axis(int x, int y)
  {
    // Each if and else if statement dictates what symbol needs to go where for the axes
    // If there is nothing to be drawn, there will simply be a blank space
    if (x == 15 && y== 0) return ">";
    else if(x == 0 && y == 15) return "^";
    else if (x == 0 && y == 0 )return ".";
    else if(x == 0 && y >= 0) return "|";
    else if(x >= 0 && y==0) return "-";
    else return "";
  }       
}
```

All that does is run an infinite loop of '-' and I don't know exactly what's wrong. 
Also, I need to figure out how I can extend the axes in either direction should an input that is greater than the 15x15 axes is entered.

If anyone could coach me through this, I would really appreciate it. I'm not asking for it to be done for me. I really want to figure this out but I'm a bit stuck right now and very frustrated.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: your for loops will never end: `for(int y = yAxismin; y >= yAxismin; y++)`. Didn't you have in mind this: `for(int y = yAxismin; y <= yAxismax; y++)`?

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj to be fair they will end. It'll just take a very long time. But that is the problem haha

Comment: Andy helped me out with that part. Thanks though! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you want to loop from `yAxismin` to `yAxismax` (and ditto for x)? Try

```
for(int y = yAxismin; y <= yAxismax; y++)
{
  for(int x = xAxismin; x <= xAxismax; x++)
  {
```

As you have it, the loop `for(int y = yAxismin; y >= yAxismin; y++)` will just go on for a very very long time. This as your expression says "start at `yAxismin`; loop while `y` is more than `yAxismin`; and on each iteration add one to `y`". You need it to *stop* when `y` reaches `yAxismax`.

Also, don't compare strings with `==` and `!=`. Use `s1.equals(s2)`. You make this mistake on the line

```
if (Axis(x,y) != "") {
```

which should be

```
if (!Axis(x, y).equals("")) {
```

To extend the axes, just pass the limits to the `Axis` function:

```
public static String Axis(int x, int y, int maxX, int maxY)
{
    if (x == maxX && y== 0) return ">";    
    else if(x == 0 && y == maxY) return "^";     
    else if (x == 0 && y == 0 )return ".";    
    else if(x == 0 && y >= 0) return "|";    
    else if(x >= 0 && y==0) return "-";    
    else return "";    
}  
...
// call it with
String drawThis = Axis(x, y, xAxismax, yAxismax);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Now I understand why there was a seemingly infinite amount of '-'s.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I try to print the axis, it prints the axis in Quadrant IV, when I want to only print Quadrant I. Any way to fix this?

Comment: @KommanderKitten. SO's etiquette is for one query per "posted question". I recommend you mark this answer as answered, if the answer answered your original query, and then ask a new question for your follow-up query.

Comment: Ah. Okay. I'm new here and wasn't aware. Thank you again!

Comment: @KommanderKitten. It's no problem. Welcome. See ["What can I ask"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["How to Ask"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) for some guidance on getting the most out of SO.